# Space between SVG and path

Tags: svg

I am using SVG to clip an image to the shape of SVG.The screenshot I have attached is of chrome(first) and IE(second).In IE it looks very small in size.The issue is I find space between the SVG and path. I have tried out many combinations of viewBox but nothing worked out.I even scaled my SVG to 1*1 even then I am facing this issue.
[image]
[image]

```
<div>
 <svg class="svg-graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="35 35 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <g>
    <clipPath id="arch-mask" >
         <path class="st0" d="M905.33,324.23c0-4.36-3.42-7.48-7.89-7.89c-72.15-3.95-130.16-61.96-134.11-134.11
                            c-0.18-4.35-3.53-7.89-7.89-7.89H297.89c-4.36,0-7.48,3.42-7.89,7.89c-3.95,72.15-61.96,130.16-134.11,134.11
                            c-4.35,0.18-7.89,3.53-7.89,7.89v457.55c0,4.36,3.42,7.48,7.89,7.89c72.15,3.95,130.16,61.96,134.11,134.11
                            c0.18,4.35,3.53,7.89,7.89,7.89h457.55c4.36,0,7.48-3.42,7.89-7.89c3.95-72.15,61.96-130.16,134.11-134.11
       </clipPath>
       </g> 
       <image clip-path="url(#arch-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/500/500" />
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code like the path that isn't closing. I've changed the viewBox of the svg element so that you have no spaces between the clipping path and the borders of the svg element. Also I've changed the size and the position of the image to be the same as the bounding box of the clipping path. To get the bounding box you can use the [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method.

In javaScript you'll find commented out the bounding box of the path inside the clipping path.

```js
/*let bb = document.querySelector("#arch-mask path").getBBox();
console.log(bb)*/
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg class="svg-graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="148 174 757.33 757.33" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <g>
    <clipPath id="arch-mask" >
         <path class="st0" d="M905.33,324.23c0-4.36-3.42-7.48-7.89-7.89c-72.15-3.95-130.16-61.96-134.11-134.11
                            c-0.18-4.35-3.53-7.89-7.89-7.89H297.89c-4.36,0-7.48,3.42-7.89,7.89c-3.95,72.15-61.96,130.16-134.11,134.11
                            c-4.35,0.18-7.89,3.53-7.89,7.89v457.55c0,4.36,3.42,7.48,7.89,7.89c72.15,3.95,130.16,61.96,134.11,134.11
                            c0.18,4.35,3.53,7.89,7.89,7.89h457.55c4.36,0,7.48-3.42,7.89-7.89c3.95-72.15,61.96-130.16,134.11-134.11"/>
       </clipPath>
       </g> 
       <image clip-path="url(#arch-mask)" x="148" y="174" width="757.33" height="757.33" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1003/500/500" />
  </svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. It worked like a charm in all browsers except IE11. Is there any way to make it workout in IE as well. And also I have several shapes to be used across the application. Can you suggest me a way how to find the perfect viewBox

Comment: In IE you may need to set the width of the svg element for example in css. In my answet I'm explaining how to get the bounding box of the path. Use those values to build the viewBox: viewBox="bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height"

Comment: Thank you. Let me try out css in IE

Comment: I tried in CSS as well but not able to change the size of SVG in IE. Is there any other way you could suggest for IE